# How do I add a sorting feature to my MVC asp.net Core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an MVC app where users can log their create entries and see them in a table on their screen. I would like to add a feature to where the users can click on on of the **Name** header and the table sort by the name column. I am using [this docs.Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.0) to help me but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. Here's what I have so far:

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder)
    {
        ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";
        var logs = from l in _context.Log
                        select l;
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                logs = logs.OrderByDescending(l => l.Name);
                break;
            case "Date":
                logs = logs.OrderBy(l => l.Date);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                logs = logs.OrderByDescending(l => l.Date);
                break;
            case "relation":
                logs = logs.OrderByDescending(l => l.Relation);
                break;
            case "type":
                logs = logs.OrderByDescending(l => l.Type);
                break;
            default:
                logs = logs.OrderBy(l => l.Date);
                break;
        }
        return View(await logs.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string parentComment, string searchString)
    {
        // Use LINQ to get list of dates.
        IQueryable<DateTime> dateQuery = from m in _context.Log
                                        // orderby m.Date
                                        select m.Date;

        var logs = from l in _context.Log
                     select l;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            logs = logs.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parentComment))
        {
            logs = logs.Where(x => x.Type == parentComment);
        }
        Dates = new SelectList(await dateQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync());
        Log = await logs.ToListAsync();
    }
```

**View**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Log[0].Date)
            </th>
            <th>
            <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder='@ViewData["NameSortParm"]'>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Log[0].Name)
            </a>
        </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Log[0].Relation)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Log[0].Type)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Log[0].Comment)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Log)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                </th>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Relation)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I have it set up for the **Name** column in the view. When I click on it, the URL changes to let me know that the `Index()` method fired (https://localhost:5001/HSLogs?action=Index) and the page reloads. No sorting happens. Hardly anything happens. Thoughts?

Comment: So where does it go wrong?

Comment: @kaffekopp I just updated my question to answer your question. Not sure why I didn't think to add that information. Sorry about that.

Comment: When you debug, your Index() method: does the parameter sortOrder get its value?

Comment: My guess is that the `OnGetAsync()` is overriding your result

Comment: I just made some updates to my question. I found that I was using old methodology. I updated the View and the Controller but still having the same issue. @kaffekopp I'm trying to debug now so that I can see what happens to sortOrder but I think @obl is right. When I add a breakpoint to the `Index()` method and click on the column header link in the **View**, it doesn't reach the method in the controller at all.

Comment: Before you updated your question, you had an `OnGetAsync()` method, which implies this is actually the codebehind for a Razor Page. Are you using an actual controller or a Razor Page?

Comment: @ChrisPratt that was my mistake. I re-added it to my question. When I updated it, I forgot to include it. To answer your question, I think it's more closely related to a Razor page. My apologies for my ignorance as I'm fairly new to the field.

Comment: If it's a Razor Page then you need to use `asp-page-handler="Index"`, instead of `asp-action="Index"`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I updated it to `<a asp-page-handler="Index" asp-route sortOrder='@ViewData["NameSortParm"]'>Name</a>` but it's still doing the same thing. The link is now going to `https://localhost:5001/HSLogs?handler=Index`. Do I need to define a Route template in **Startup.Configure**?

Comment: There are some new developments! I changed the `Index(string sortOrder)` method to `OnGetIndex(string sortOrder)`. Now when I click on the link (column header) it triggers the `Index()` method in the controller. @kaffekopp I found that `sortOrder` is reading as null all the way through.

Comment: According to the comments above, is it a pure razor pages project, or a combination of mvc and razor page? If it is just a razor pages project, you could refer to this link about sorting in razor pages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xueli Chen's suggestion worked. Thank you.

I got rid of the `Task<T> Index` method in the controller. I moved the switch statement to the `Task OnGetAsync()` method and updated the syntax.

**Controller:**

```
public string NameSort { get; set; }
public string DateSort { get; set; }    

public async Task OnGetAsync(string sortOrder)
    {
        NameSort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        DateSort = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

        IQueryable<Log> logsEntry = from s in _context.Log
                                        select s;
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "name_desc":
                logsEntry = logsEntry.OrderByDescending(l => l.Name);
                break;
            case "Date":
                logsEntry = logsEntry.OrderBy(l => l.Date);
                break;
            case "date_desc":
                logsEntry = logsEntry.OrderByDescending(l => l.Date);
                break;
            default:
                logsEntry = logsEntry.OrderBy(l => l.Date);
                break;
        }

        Log = await logsEntry.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }
```

In the View, I updated the header links with the appropriate tag-helpers for the Date column and the Name column.

**View**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.DateSort">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Log[0].Date)
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.NameSort">
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Log[0].Name)
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Log[0].Relation)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Log[0].Type)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Log[0].Comment)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
         ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy an reusable way to do sorting on Asp.net core 5.0

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Query query)
{
   var models = await _context.model.AsQueryable();

   var columnName = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Model, object>>>()
   {
      ["name"] = m => m.name,
      ["date"] = m => m.date
   } 

   models = query.IsSortByAscending 
         ? models.SortBy(columnName[query.SortBy])
         : models.OrderByDescending(columnName[query.SortBy])
}
```

If you want to add more columns for sorting you just need to add column name as the key in the Dictionay and also it's value (in the form of lamba expression).